# Flutter: Show different widget conditionally

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm making an app where I want to show a progress indicator before the API returns some data. If there is any data on the API call then I want to show Widget-A or else Widget-B. But I'm not sure how to show Widget-B.

I'm only able to do the following so far...

```
list!.isNotEmpty
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list!["filtered"]["data"].length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                      '${list!["filtered"]["data"][index]["strikePrice"]}'),
                );
              },
            )
          : LinearProgressIndicator(),
    );
```

Here `ListView.builder()` is Widget-A and a button would be Widget-B, which IDK how to show if list is empty.

Can you help me achieve this? TIA.

Comment: Could you share the code of how are you retrieving the data?

Comment: Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330896/flutter-http-request-sometimes-shows-error. This is my post with different problem but the app is same and the code for fetching the data is shared here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could track if it's loading or not like this:

```
class _NiftyScreenState extends State<NiftyScreen> {
  Map<String, dynamic>? niftyDetails = {};
  late bool isLoading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getNiftyDetails();
  }

  getNiftyDetails() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      this.niftyDetails = await fetchNiftyData();
    catch (err) {
      print(err);
      // Here you can save the error message if you want to show it
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading
          ? LinearProgressIndicator()
          : niftyDetails!.isNotEmpty
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: niftyDetails!["filtered"]["data"].length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                          '${niftyDetails!["filtered"]["data"][index]["strikePrice"]}'),
                    );
                  },
                )
              : WidgetB(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There's an issue with this code... If the api call is fetching data then setState((){isLoading = false}); works. But if it fails to fetch any data then the setState((){isLoading = false}); doesn't work. I couldn't figure out the issue here.

Comment: That's because if there's an error that line is not called. You could wrap that remote call with a try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

Take a boolean variable, let's say `bool _isLoading;`
Just before you trigger your API call set it to true `setState(() { _isLoading = true });`,
then as soon as you receive response from your API set the boolean value to false `setState(() { _isLoading = false});`.
Lastly,

```
 !_isLoading?  
        list!.isNotEmpty
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list!["filtered"]["data"].length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                      '${list!["filtered"]["data"][index]["strikePrice"]}'),
                );
              },
            )
          : Container(
            child: Text("list is empty"), // show whatever you'd like to when list is empty
          ) 
        : LinearProgressIndicator(),
    );
```

Comment: There's an issue with this code... If the api call is fetching data then setState((){isLoading = false}); works. But if it fails to fetch any data then the setState((){isLoading = false}); doesn't work. I couldn't figure out the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a layout builder

```dart
list!.isNotEmpty
  ? LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      final remoteList = list!["filtered"]["data"];
      if (remoteList.isNotEmpty) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list!["filtered"]["data"].length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return ListTile(
            title: Text(
            '${list!["filtered"]["data"][index]["strikePrice"]}'),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return WidgetB();
      }
    },
    ),
  : LinearProgressIndicator(),
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your approach. But I think LayoutBuilder() would be a bit too much for the given problem as I currently have no issues which will require constraints. But thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. One way of doing is by setting a variable before the condition.

   Widget widgetToShow = (some condition) ? widgetA : WidgetB;

   list!.isNotEmpty
   ? widgetToShow
   : LinearProgressIndicator(),
   );
2. or just use one variable for everything, using IF of CASE statements to handle 3 possible widgets(A, B and ProgressIndicator).